# openerp web client 6.1: how to override base javascript functions

Tags: client, web, webclient, odoo

I'm looking for a way to override some openerp web js core functions such as "on_logout".

The docs lack of instructions (as you can see in [my post](http://planet.domsense.com/en/2012/01/openerp-new-web-client-6-1-documentation/)) and the [helloworld module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openerp-web/trunk/view/head:/addons/web_hello/static/openerp/base_hello.js) tells you that you can do it like

```
openerp.web_hello = function(openerp) {

openerp.web.SearchView = openerp.web.SearchView.extend({
    init:function() {
        this._super.apply(this,arguments);
        this.on_search.add(function(){console.log('hello');});
    }
});

// here you may tweak globals object, if any, and play with on_* or do_* callbacks on them

openerp.web.Login = openerp.web.Login.extend({
    start: function() {
        console.log('Hello there');
        this._super.apply(this,arguments);
    }
});

};
```

In my module I'm doing this:

```
openerp.mytest = function(openerp){

    openerp.web.WebClient = openerp.web.WebClient.extend({
        on_logout: function() {
            alert('mine');
            [...]
        },
    });
}
```

I know js is loaded since putting an alert outside this definition works.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bit of a special issue since you want to alter the prototype (the class, if you will) of an object which is already instantiated (a WebClient instance is the root of the system, so it's probably already there by the time your code is loaded, therefore creating a new WebClient "class" won't alter the existing instance).

In that case, you can't replace the class with a subclass, you have to re-open the class (in a manner similar to Ruby), for that there is an `include` method on class objects, which *should* work:

```js
openerp.mytest = function(openerp) {
    openerp.web.WebClient.include({
        on_logout: function() {
            alert('mine');
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
}
```

(as in Ruby, `this._super` is bound to the method you're replacing, if any, for in-place class alterations)

If you check the view_list_editable.js implementation file, it provides examples of that since it needs to reopen and alter the listview's code in order to add editability.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I just tried this but is not working. It continues to use the original one. FWIW I just pulled the latest release.

Comment: Oh hell, I'd forgotten that this was a "callback" (`on_*` and `do_*` methods are bound directly to instances during `init` if the class extends `openerp.web.CallbackEnabled` somehow), and `WebClient` is instanced before any module is loaded. Your only solution is to use raw javascript, and access `openerp.webclient` (the webclient instance for this session, if any) and alter it directly. Something like `openerp.webclient.on_logout.add_first(function () { console.log('my logout')});` works. Replacing on_logout likely will not work because the events are bound eagerly (a bad idea).

Comment: I tried: openerp.mytest = function(openerp) {
    openerp.webclient.on_logout.add_first(
        function () {
            alert('thatsme!');
        }
    );
} but it's seem useless as well :(

Comment: OK now that's downright weird, that's basically what I added to the "hello" test/demo module: `openerp.web_hello = function(openerp) { openerp.webclient.on_logout.add_first(function () {alert('thatsme!');});` and it displays the alert correctly on logout. Are you sure you don't have a javascript error which prevents this code from loading or executing?

Comment: OK, I got it! Here are the reason why it didn't work: a) you must not use "openerp.web.WebClient" but its alias "openerp.webclient" (as you've done in last example) - b) you MUST use your real module's name for the main function declaration. Mine was not really "mytest". I used that just to ask the question and try it. That's my fault, since it's one of the few things pointed out into the docs.

Comment: I took the time to write few lines about this: http://planet.domsense.com/en/2012/01/openerp-new-web-client-6-1-javascript-hooks/